# why scrapy pipline doesnot get call from parser method?

Tags: python, scrapy

I created a simple scrapy project that scrape a web page and save the data to the postgresql. I can get all the scraped data in my parse method but the pipline doesnot get called to save the data to the database. Here is my spider parse method.

```py
    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.css('a::attr(href)').getall()
        if links is not None:
            for link in links:
                yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse)
        else:
            loader = ItemLoader(item=TestItem(), selector=response)
            quote = response.css('div.quote p::text').get()
            loader.add_value('quote', title)

            yield loader.load_item()
```

Here is the `TestItem`

```py
class TestItem(scrapy.Item):
    quote = scrapy.Field()
```

Here is the `pipline`

```py
class TestPipeline:
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
            logging.log(logging.INFO, item)
            print(item)
            quote = Quote(text=item.quote)
            db.session.add(quote)
            db.session.commit()
        return item
```

Finaly the `pipline` is called in setting

```py
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   'Test.pipelines.TestPipeline': 300,
}
```

Any help is welcome.
I printed the `item` in pipline. Here is the ouput.

```
2021-07-16 09:54:33 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.5.0 started (bot: Quote)
2021-07-16 09:54:33 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.6.3.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 21.2.0, Python 3.9.6 (tags/v3.9.6:db3ff76, Jun 28 2021, 15:26:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 20.0.1 (OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021), cryptography 3.4.7, Platform Windows-10-10.0.19043-SP0
2021-07-16 09:54:33 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2021-07-16 09:54:33 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'Quote',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'Quote.spiders',
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['Quote.spiders']}
2021-07-16 09:54:33 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 88264e27a8108b1f
2021-07-16 09:54:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2021-07-16 09:54:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2021-07-16 09:54:33 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2021-07-16 09:54:34 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['Quote.pipelines.QuotePipeline']
2021-07-16 09:54:34 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2021-07-16 09:54:34 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2021-07-16 09:54:34 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2021-07-16 09:54:34 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.azquotes.com/quotes/topics/inspirational.html/> from <GET http://azquotes.com/quotes/topics/inspirational.html/>
2021-07-16 09:54:36 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.azquotes.com/quotes/topics/inspirational.html/> (referer: None)
2021-07-16 09:54:36 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2021-07-16 09:54:36 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 494,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 23417,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 2.771838,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 16, 0, 54, 36, 828890),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 107443,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 16, 0, 54, 34, 57052)}
2021-07-16 09:54:36 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: could you print `item` in process_item and add the output on your question please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is being called.

```
from ..items import TestItem

class Something(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "something"
    start_urls = ['http://azquotes.com/quotes/topics/inspirational.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.css('a::attr(href)').getall()
        #if links is not None:
        #    for link in links:
        #        yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse)
        #else:
        loader = ItemLoader(item=TestItem(), selector=response)
        quote = response.css('div.quote p::text').get()
        title = "some_title"
        loader.add_value('quote', title)

        yield loader.load_item()
```

will print (I added 'print("called")' to process_item function):

```
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.azquotes.com/quotes/topics/inspirational.html> (referer: None)
[root] INFO: {'quote': ['some_title']}
{'quote': ['some_title']}
called
[scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.azquotes.com/quotes/topics/inspirational.html>
{'quote': ['some_title']}
```

When you yield an item the 'process_item' function is called, but you're getting some errors because you try to follow some non-existing pages (like `<a href="#">`).

From what I'm seeing you're trying to scrape all the quotes from the site, if I'm correct then this is what you need to do:

1. Make a function that will scrape all quotes from just one of the pages.
2. Create crawling rules for the links you want to follow (more info [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=crawlspider#crawlspider).)
3. Change to crawl spider:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from ..items import TestItem

class Something(CrawlSpider):
    name = "something"
    start_urls = ['http://azquotes.com/quotes/topics/inspirational.html']

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(........),)
    def parse(self, response):
........
........
........
```